# How can I get user location in apple watch?

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, watchos-2

I want to detect user location in apple watch , can I check if watch has build in GPS or not ? so if it has (watch series 2) and if it does not (watch series 1). If it is watch series 2  it will use its GPS or iPhone location.